# REGEX Replacing with exception

Tags: regex, notepad++

my first problem here is my nemesis regex.

I need a regex to replace every `,` with a `","` from a text without replacing existing `,"`.

It looks like this:

Before:

```
abcd,efgh,ijkl,"","",mnop
```

After:

```
abcd","efgh","ijkl","","","mnop
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: it would try to use it in Nodepad++ so not a programming lanugage

Comment: down do i add a tag or alter it. Sry have never used stackoverflow before

Comment: I currently used [^(,")] to replace everything except for ," but i need to compine it with a filter and this did not work so far

Comment: Add what you tried to the question

Comment: Try `(?<!"),(?!")` and replace with `","`

Comment: quite good, but it misses a " before the "," so it look like this:  abcd","efgh","ijkl,"","","mnop. BUt thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not sure what you mean, see https://regex101.com/r/xm72L7/1, it does not miss anything.

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for this, you know? Two simple search & replaces can do the job nicely (assuming the input data follows a pattern regarding the presence of the sequence `,"`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew look again. I don't know if you can highlight  here but i marked the missing parts. abcd","efgh","ijkl(here),"","",(here)mnop

Comment: I guess you have a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crudely, I think you are after something like:

```
(?:(?<!"),"|(?<=")",(?!")|(?<!"),(?!"))
```

<sup>**Note:** As mention by @WiktorStribiżew in the comments you could get rid of the outer non-capturing group: `(?<!"),"|(?<=")",(?!")|(?<!"),(?!")`</sup>

See the online [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xm72L7/2)

Comment: Thanks, jeez I really have to get into regex. Thank you very much

Comment: @Iniour The `(?:","|\G[^,]+)\K"?,"?` regex is not simple, do not feel intimidated. It is actually a bit wrong since start of string position must be subtracted from `\G` and it is really ugly in NPP (it must be `\G(?!^(?<![\s\S]))`). In most cases, it will still work as expected.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I have realized before your comment and reverted back to my original crude alternation.

Comment: Yeah, that is good. You just do not need the outer non-capturing group, it is equal to `(?<!"),"|(?<=")",(?!")|(?<!"),(?!")`. I'd suggest keeping it since it worked for OP.

Comment: Good catch, It's a habit of mine... thanks for the eagle eye!

Answer (score 1):

Solving a problem using regular expressions is nice [but now you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247).

A simple solution that does not involve the usage of regular expressions to is do three simple string replacements: first replace `,` with `","` then replace `",""` with `","` and in the end `"","` with `","`.

Let's see why this works:

```
          |  after 1st  |  after 2nd  |  after 3rd
 original | replacement | replacement | replacement
----------+-------------+-------------+-------------
   a,b    |   a","b     |   a","b     |   a","b 
   m",n   |   m"","n    |   m"","n    |   m","n
   x,"y   |   x",""y    |   x","y     |   x","y
```

See it in action:

```js
const input = 'abcd,efgh,ijkl,"","",mnop';

const output = input.replace(/,/g, '","').replace(/",""/g, '","').replace(/"","/g, '","');

console.log(output);
```

N.B. The code snippet above uses regular expressions because this is how JavaScript implements the "replace all" functionality. When the first argument of [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a string it replaces only its first occurrence.
I could use [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) instead (it works with strings) but it is [not widely supported by browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll#Browser_compatibility) yet.

Comment: Jeez you are right. Why take the easy way, when you can take the hard one... I thought way to complicated.

Comment: unfortunatley i cannot accept two solutions and with the complicated regex from JvdV it easier for me. But thank you, for this easy and elegant solution.

Comment: It doesn't mean we cannot upvote it since it's helpfull in any case and possibly "a better tool for the job"! +